# How to set up Wifi Windows 10 No Mouse or Keyboard

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm working in a situation where we need to ship an Intel compute stick with Windows 10 Pro installed out to our customers who will then plug this into a TV and need to connect it to the local wifi without a mouse or a keyboard. Ideally using their iPhone or Android device.

Does anyone have any ideas or experience with how this could be done?

Things I have tried so far:

1. Create a local hotspot from the device and have the user connect to that temporary hotspot and exchange credentials at that time. The problem with this approach is it seems the hardware needs "Hosted network supported" which seems like is going away due to driver updates and the hardware we are using doesn't support it at least.
2. Connect to the device using bluetooth. My research so far makes this look extremely complicated, if it's even possible.

I appreciate any and all suggestions. It is possible for us to switch devices, if for example this was easily done on a raspberry pi or something similar. They just need to be fairly cheap.

Comment: Are you sure `hostednetwork` is not supported? I believe it is disabled by default but can be enabled using cmd.

Comment: I believe so although it's a new concept to me. When I run "netsh wlan show drivers" it shows hosted network supported : "No" and I haven't found any way to reliably change that

Answer (score 0):

I would quail at the thought of walking Joe User through pairing up a phone to use it as a Bluetooth keyboard/mouse peripheral, even those apps exist in the the Google Store. To save my sanity, I would either

1. Bundle it with an inexpensive USB hub, keyboard and mouse.
2. Look in Intel's Product Compatibility page for Sticks [to find the list of Intel's tested and approved](http://compatibleproducts.intel.com/ProductDetails?activeModule=Intel%C2%AE%20Compute%20Stick#) Bluetooth keyboards and mice, and pair those up before you ship.

Comment: The intent is for the compute stick to basically be a display screen so the only substantial input needed on the user side is original wifi network setup. Was hoping we could make this possible for them to just plug into their TV and a display screen would pop up prompting them through the rest of the process

Comment: Don't know how you could. You'd have to 'pair' it to use Bluetooth, which requires real time input from the Compute Stick. Likewise, connecting to the local WiFi requires real time  input from the Computer Stick.